# how to change the grid line color in plotly scatter plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I use plotly dash to draw the following scatter charts, and how can I change the grid line color
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To customize the grid in plotly, do the following. This will allow you to display the grid on the xy axis, set the line width and line color.

```
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='LightPink')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='LightPink')
```

Comment: More information can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-gridcolor). If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer